# Вывод из бд, по конкретному id, как проверить id?

Tags: php, ооп, mvc, httpbackend

Есть страница с ,,предложениями,, (div - блоками) в них располагаются данные которые берутся из бд. У каждого такого блока есть свой id, который так же берется из базы.
Вопрос состоит в следующем, как по нажатию кнопки (на карту) передать на другую страницу именно конкретный id, или точнее как отобразить только данные по выбранному id.

форма:

```
   <?php foreach($data as $item) { ?>
        <div class="col-sm-4 , cf">         
          <ul  class="list-group">         
            <li class="list-group-item active"> <b>Offer № :</b> <?=$item['id']?> <a href="/map/"><button style="margin-top: -3px;  height: 27px !important;
            float: right;" class="btn btn-sm btn-success"  >На карту</button></a></li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Name company : <?=$item['name_company']?></li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Place car : <?=$item['place_car']?></li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Contact Email : <?=$item['cont_email']?></li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Contact phone : <?=$item['cont_phone']?></li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Start point : <?=$item['start_p']?></li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Finish point : <?=$item['finish_p']?></li>          
          </ul>          
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
```

По нажатию на кнопку в текст фиелд должна попасть запись связанная только с тем айди от которого была нажата кнопка. 
возможно нужно условие, но я не могу понять как его реализовтаь...

```
<?php foreach($data as $item)  { ?>
      <label for="from">From:</label>
      <input type="text" id="from" name="from" required="required" placeholder="An address" size="30" value="<?=$item['start_p']?>" />
      <a id="from-link" href="#">Get my position</a>
      <br />

      <label style="margin-right: 21px;" for="to">To:</label>
      <input type="text" id="to" name="to" required="required" placeholder="Another address" size="30" value="<?=$item['finish_p']?>" />
      <a id="to-link" href="#">Get my position</a>
      <br />
<?php }?>
```

Код контроллера:

```
<?php
class MapController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct($data = array() ){
        parent::__construct($data);
        $this->model = new Customer();
    }

    public function index(){
        $this->data = $this->model->getList();
    }   
}
```

Модель customer:

```
<?php 

CLass Customer extends Model{

    public function getList(){
        $sql = "select * from seller_info where 1";
        return $this->db->query($sql);
    }
}
```

Comment: `<a href="/map?id=<?=$item['id']?>"><button type="button" ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в контроллер добавил функцию выбирающую по id записи из бд:

```
public function get_id(){
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $sql = "select * from seller_info where id='{$id}' ";
    return $this->db->query($sql);
}
```

соответственно в контроллере поменял вызов функции :

```
public function index(){
    $this->data = $this->model->get_id();
}
```

и по подсказке Igor-а (коммент выше), добавил

```
 <a href="/map?id=<?=$item['id']?>/">
```

в итоге в сборке оно работает корректно.